# how are transient variable carrying state across network?

Tags: java, serialization

We have a server receiving reqests from CLI, and were using a very basic POJO to store the state being transfered in a single object.  This object is ultimately serilized over the network using an OjbectStream to our server, which reads it in and uses the data to process the request.  It works perfectly fine as expected.  However, when I happened to open up the POJO today to expand it I noticed it looked like this (written by memory since I can't copy and paste)

```
class param {
    private transient String input;
    private transient String output;

    public param(String input, String output){
         this.input=input;
         this.output=output;
    }

   public String getInput(){
         return input;
   }

   public String getOutput(){
        return output;
   }
}
```

How does this POJO work?  if the input and output strings, the only variables it has, are both transient then when it's read off the network by the server shouldn't I get an empty input and output string and thus be unable to do anythinhg?  I know it works, I just can't figure out why it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does this POJO work?

Most like the class also has a `writeObject` and `readObject` methods which serialize and deserialize those fields.

> if the input and output strings, the only variables it has, are both transient then when it's read off the network by the server shouldn't I get an empty input and output string and thus be unable to do anythinhg?

You should be getting `null` otherwise not empty string.

> I know it works, I just can't figure out why it does

Most likely there is code you missed.  Or it is not using Java Serialization.  Other serialization libraries may ignore `transient`.